# Azure SQL server Handling both EST and EDT in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, azure-sql-database, where-clause

I am currently comparing the date field in my Azure SQL server DB to check if the `OrderDate`
field is equal to the today's date in Eastern Time zone. Below is what I am trying

```
 OrderDate = convert(date, dateadd(hour,-5,GETUTCDATE()), 23)
```

But found that `hour,-5` won't handle locations that change to Eastern Daylight Time (EDT). How can I compare the `OrderDate` with Today's date in Eastern Time zone which can work on both EST and EDT

Comment: No SQL Server to test on atm, but something like `OrderDate = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time')` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database always follows UTC. Use AT TIME ZONE in SQL Database if you need to interpret date and time information in a non-UTC time zone.

```
SELECT convert(date,getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') as Eastern_date
```

[image]

You can refer the list of installed time zones available in sys.time_zone_info view.

`select * from sys.time_zone_info`

[image]